# what does "As easy as it is to spend money today" mean?

Tags: grammar

In this sentence, "As easy as it is to spend money today, saving money is important.", what does "as easy as" mean?
I know that "as...as..." usually is used when comparing two people or things, like "You're as tall as your father." But in "As easy as it is to spend money", "spend money" has no object to compare. So what does it mean? How should I understand this sentence?

Comment: The word ***today*** tells us the implied comparison is with how "relatively difficult" it was to spend money ***in the past*** (when people lived simpler lives, with more *bartering*, less material goods to buy, and no credit cards).

Comment: (Obviously there's a "secondary" comparison being made between ***spending*** money and ***saving*** money.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This introductory phrase in the sentence could be roughly paraphrased as

> It is easy to spend money, but ...

or

> Even though it is easy to spend money ...

It is derived from the As-as construction but the comparison is empty "As easy as it is easy". The contrast with the main part of the sentence "saving money is important"  is part of the idiom.  You use this expression to create contrast.

> As tall as he was, Jack couldn't reach the top shelf.